# Python 3 socket

Tags: python-3.x, sockets

This is probably a very silly question, but I can't understand why the code below doesn't work:

```
import socket
host = "127.0.0.1"
port = 23

mySocket = socket.socket()
mySocket.connect((host,port))

messages = [b"test",b"test2"]

for msg in messages:
    mySocket.sendall(msg)
    data = mySocket.recv(1024).decode(errors="ignore")
    print("Received from server :" + data)

mySocket.close()
```

I will receive the response to the first request only. The second request is sent (I checked it with Wireshark) but I would not get any answer (no reply packet in Wireshark) and the script get stuck.

How should I proceed if I want to send multiple messages?

Any hint appreciated,
Thank you,

Comment: If the server will send something back or not is completely up to the server you connect to (in this case maybe a telnet daemon based on the port)  and the client cannot force the server to send a reply. You are assuming a specific behavior of the server which the server you've connected to does not have.

Comment: I understand. But it should send something back (the same reply as the first one). So why it doesn't ? I suspect this is related to the way I coded it (something to do with TCP internals) and that it isn't the proper way to do.

Comment: What makes you sure that the server should send something back? If I run your code against a test server which actually sends something back it works perfectly. So the problem is not your code but the wrong assumptions you make about the servers behavior.

Comment: Because the two requests are exactly the same, that's why I'm assuming it should respond two times. Why it will only answer one request and not the other one (moody server :P) ? More seriously, I have the same problem with a real application (that should respond to a request and doesn't while it does with the dedicated client), I replicated the problem with telnet just to be able to post it on StackOverflow.

Comment: Your are assuming that the server you connect to works like a web server, i.e. same request results (most times) in same response. But this behavior is specific for a web server, not for any arbitrary server and especially not for a telnet server. And you cannot simply take a problem you have with for example a web server and replicate it with a telnet server since these servers behave differently. So you should probably better ask about the real problem and not the play problem you have.

Comment: Hm. Ok, I think I'm going to try a different approach. Thank you for your answers.